# how to import image to JLabel?

Tags: image, jframe, label

Here is my code that should display an image and a button below it

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame title");
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Green.png"));
frame.add(label);
frame.add(new JButton("SPIN"));
```

[Project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo53t.png)

I've done this so far, but no image appears on JFrame. The picture is in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Green.png"));
```

by

```
 label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(YourMainClassName.class.getResource("Green.png")));
```

This code tries to load image relative to you project, instead of directory, you are running it from. See [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) section in Java Tutorial for more information.

This code will become even better, if the following fix is applied:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame title");
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// Moved below
// frame.pack();
// frame.setVisible(true);

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(YourMainClassName.class.getResource("Green.png")));

// Added items go to content pane directly
frame.getContentPane().add(label);
frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("SPIN"));

// Moved from above
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Notice that `JFrame` contains no content when `pack` is called in the original code, so it will try to minimize window size, and `setVisible` will show empty frame first. After that, when each component is added, the frame will needs a relayout.

Modified coded fixes both of this problems: `pack` will adjust window size to the real content and only one layout pass will be necessary.

The second change is how to add components to frame. It is better to add them to the frames content pane, instead of adding to the frame directly. You may find more information about it in [Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) section of Java Tutorial.